# How can I pause audio in UIWebView when I play audio use AVPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, avaudiosession, avplayeritem

I have a `UIWebView` playing music, when I play audio using `AVPlayer`, they play together.

I try to use `AVAudioSession` to control this. But not working.

Here is my code

```
- (IBAction)click:(id)sender {

  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mmmono.qiniudn.com/1c16bee1df0dbfbfea04ae11d8d8d021.mp3"];
  self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
  [self.player play];

  [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];
  [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mmmono.com/g/meow/560885/"];
  [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
}
```

Comment: Copy/paste your code, do not put a screenshot. Link can dies, and also if we want to just rectify a line or two, we have to type it again, whereas if you copied/pasted it, we just have to copy/paste it too to modify it.

Comment: I think as when UIWebView loads the page or site then you could stop the play of music. Else according to documentation there is no way to know whether music is played or not.

Answer (score 1):

Never try this but you can use javascript and UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString to find all audio tag on your WebView and set each DOM stop play audio by using javascript "pause()" function like so.

Prepare javascript function. (If you have html, javascript of that web you can write below function direct in .js file or `<script>` tag)

```
NSString *pauseScriptString = @"function pauseAllAudio() {\
  var audios = document.getElementsByTagName(\"audio\");\
  if(audios.length > 0){\
  for(var i = 0; i< audios.length; i++){\
    audios[i].pause();\
  }\
 }\
}";
```

Load javascript to webview so you can call it execute later.

```
[yourWebview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: pauseScriptString];
```

Execute pausescript

```
[youWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pauseAllAudio()"]];
```